# how to install flatland icon theme in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to install flatland icon theme but it doesn't show up when I do command + p.
Their installation instruction says 
`Some people have reported that they cannot find the extension when they insert the installation command:` 
`ext install vscode-flatland-icon-theme`.

my question is where do I run `ext install vscode-flatland-icon-theme`. I tried running it in my terminal and it says `command not found`.

How do I go about this?

Comment: Press `F1`, then `Backspace`, then type `ext install vscode-flatland-icon-theme`.

Comment: This doesn't work on mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Preferences: File Icon theme  (from the command palette)
2. Install Additional File Icon Themes
3. search for flatland - choose one, install it, reload
4. Command palette again: Preferences: File Icon theme
5. Choose your new theme

Comment: I got it with slightly different approach: `command + p`. Then type `> icon`. This shows `preference: file icon theme` in the dropdown. Then select `preference: file icon theme`. Select `none`.